# Create a repository; user input data from input box and data is saved in the other sheet

Tags: excel

I need to create an input box wherein I have the multiple input boxes to input multiple information. They are:
-Enter Dealer Name
-Enter Dealer Number
-VPR level
-Pack Level
-Install Date
-Action
-Review Date
-Loss Ratio

And once the user enters all the information and clicks on Submit button, the information gets copied to a different sheet and acts as a repository. And when multiple data are entered, the data gets copied to the repository sheet from the next available blank row onward.

I need Macro for this, can anyone help me how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rename the controls to conform to what is in the code.
The code below is in ther userform.

I hope it helps.

```
Private Sub cmdConfirmEntry_Click()
    Dim iNumNonEmpty, iRowNumCurr, iColNumCurr As Integer
    Worksheets("test entries").Activate
        With ActiveSheet
          Range("A1").Select
          iColNumCurr = Range("A1").Column
          iRowNumCurr = Range("A1").Row
          iNumNonEmpty = Range("A1:A10000").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
          Cells(iRowNumCurr + iNumNonEmpty, iColNumCurr).Activate

          Cells(ActiveCell.Row, iColNumCurr) = Me.txtDealerName.Value
          Cells(ActiveCell.Row, iColNumCurr + 1) = Me.txtDealerNumber.Value
          Cells(ActiveCell.Row, iColNumCurr + 2) = Me.txtVPRLevel.Value
          Cells(ActiveCell.Row, iColNumCurr + 3) = Me.txtPacLevel.Value
          Cells(ActiveCell.Row, iColNumCurr + 4) = Me.txtInstallDate.Value
          Cells(ActiveCell.Row, iColNumCurr + 5) = Me.txtAction.Value
          Cells(ActiveCell.Row, iColNumCurr + 6) = Me.txtReviewDate.Value
          Cells(ActiveCell.Row, iColNumCurr + 7) = Me.txtLoasRation.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Why am I getting ME error while trying to run this code?

Comment: All the controls in my case are sitting on the userform. So this sub is behind the userform. In my case, "me" refers to userform as the parent object.

Comment: How about  Once the user adds all the details, how do I go and add a Submit button, so that once clicked on Submit, the data gets copied to the next sheet, And when multiple information are submitted, I want the next sheet to act as a repository. The next set of data gets submitted from the next line onwards, How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using `Activate` and `Select`.  This may be what you are looking for, but you will need to adjust things like the Sheet Name and so on..

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Cells(LastRow, 1).Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = UserForm1.TextBox3.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 4).Value = UserForm1.TextBox4.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 5).Value = UserForm1.TextBox5.Value
    Cells(LastRow, 6).Value = UserForm1.TextBox6.Value

    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: How about adding a button to the dialog box and once you click on submit, the data gets saved in the next sheet

Comment: This code has helped me create a dialog box, but Once the user adds all the details, how do I go and add a Submit button, so that once clicked on Submit, the data gets copied to the next sheet, And when multiple information are submitted, I want the next sheet to act as a repository. The next set of data gets submitted from the next line onwards, How do I do that?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply.  In VBA you will need to add a Command Button to the UserForm by selecting the UserForm and then in the toolbox add the Command Button.  Once the Command Button has been added then place your code in the `CommandButton_Change ()` event.  Please do some research on adding controls to UserForms as well.